# Json Wrapped object Post always null

Tags: c#, json, wcf

[Edited message with more info and fiddler requests]

I am trying to call a Post webmethod server side defined like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, 
           UriTemplate = "SaveMessage")]
void SaveMessage(Message msg);
```

the Message class is defined as such:

```
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FromId { get; set; }
    public int ToId { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string Msg { get; set;}
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }
}
```

with the following Request (wrapped):

```
POST http://192.168.2.40:9001/AFMServer/SaveMessage HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: 192.168.2.40:9001
Content-Length: 204
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive
{
  "msg": {
    "Id": 0,
    "FromId": 0,
    "ToId": 0,
    "Subject": null,
    "From": "",
    "To": null,
    "DateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "Msg": null,
    "IsRead": false
  }
}
```

The request is **NOT** received server side although it's wrapped as specified by the WebInvoke property.

The following (bare) request however:

```
POST http://192.168.2.40:9001/AFMServer/SaveMessage HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: 192.168.2.40:9001
Content-Length: 169
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive
{
  "Id": 0,
  "FromId": 0,
  "ToId": 0,
  "Subject": null,
  "From": "",
  "To": null,
  "DateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "Msg": null,
  "IsRead": false
}
```

Is received but msg is null (which makes sense, I guess, since the json is not wrapped).
Can somebody help me find out why the first request is unsuccessful?

Thanks!

NB: I am using **Json.Net**

[EDIT 2]
**If I remove the DateTime field from the Message class, it WORKS! Still trying to figure out why**

[EDIT 3]
Workaround is written below as an answer - HTH! :-)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: How do you set Content-type?

Comment: Can you capture raw request using fiddler?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Message class looks like this:

```
public class Message
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int FromId { get; set; }
  public int ToId { get; set; }
  public string Subject { get; set; }
  public string From { get; set; }
  public string To { get; set; }
  public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
  public string Msg { get; set; }
  public bool IsRead { get; set; }
}
```

Then making your JSON look like this:

```
{
    "Id": 0,
    "FromId": 0,
    "ToId": 0,
    "Subject": null,
    "From": "",
    "To": null,
    "DateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "Msg": null,
    "IsRead": false
}
```

Should map to your C# class just fine.

The important thing to keep in mind, is that each property of the JSON should map to a property on the C# object (case-sensitive).

Your JSON, as is, would map to an object that looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public Message Msg { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Second part .. not really. OP correctly uses the `msg` property because `BodyStyle`  is  `WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest`.

Comment: Just noticed the wcf tag. I assumed asp.net mvc w/ a strange action filter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems (as probably most of you already know), that JSON is quite fiddly with date formats.
Since I did not want to override the Serializer to comply to the JSON date format, I used the following work around to pass the date as a string:

```
public class Message
{
    (...)

    public DateTime DateTime { get { return DateTime.Parse(DateTimeStr); } }
    public String DateTimeStr { get; set; }

    (...)
}
```